# Synchronising drawing using PUN

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, synchronization, multiplayer, photon

I have implemented annotation feature which is similar to drawing in VR. Drawing is a Unity trail and its shape depends on its trajectory. This is where real problem comes. We are synchronising the drawing in realtime using `PhotonTransformView` which syncs world position of the trail. But [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uxEelBoL2DrRvVd0FJ3zaepSIskdxsZc/view?usp=sharing) is the output. The synchronised drawing looks so different from the original one.

Here is sync configuration code:

```
public void SetupSync(int viewId, int controllingPlayer)
{
   if (PhotonNetwork.inRoom)
   {
      photonView = gameObject.AddComponent<PhotonView>();
      photonView.ownershipTransfer = OwnershipOption.Takeover;
      photonView.synchronization = ViewSynchronization.ReliableDeltaCompressed;
      photonView.viewID = viewId;

      photonTransformView = gameObject.AddComponent<PhotonTransformView>();
      photonTransformView.m_PositionModel.SynchronizeEnabled = true;

      photonView.ObservedComponents = new List<Component>();
      photonView.ObservedComponents.Add(photonTransformView);
      photonView.TransferOwnership(controllingPlayer);
   }
}
```

How can we make the drawing on two systems more similar? I have seen cases where people have been able to synchronise these perfectly. Check [this](https://youtu.be/KcWZFpjjD34). What are they doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PhotonTransformView is not suitable for this.

You could send a reliable rpc every x milliseconds with the list of points since the last rpc. That's when it's being drawn live, and when the drawing is finished, you cache the whole drawing definition in a database given a drawing Id. Then drawings can be retrieved later by players joining the room after the drawing was done or even loaded from a list of drawing or by any arbitrary logic.

All in all you need two different system, one when drawing is live, and one when drawing is done.

Comment: Thanks Jean. What length of points array should be suitable? 500 should be good, or it should cause bandwidth issues?

Comment: Also, what should be the rpc rate? Every 50ms should do fine?

Comment: @HarshPriyadarshi Can we continue this conversation on the Photon Forum, StackOverflow is not suitable for long discussion by design. 500 seems reasonnable though but you could buffer and send in bunches as well.

Answer (score 0):

Martjin Pieters's answer is the correct way to do it.
But for those who have the same problem for a different situations, it comes from this line:

`photonView.synchronization = ViewSynchronization.ReliableDeltaCompressed;`

It's basically compressing data and not sending the new one if it's too close to the last data sent. Just switch it `Unreliable` and all the data will be directly sent.